# Turning a callback function into promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to convert this code into promise (The one that i commented //). My goal is to print the user's location (longitude and latitude) but I'm having a hard time figuring it out, on how to convert this into Promise. (Sorry for my english)

```
// const getUserLocation = () => {
//     if (navigator.geolocation) {
//         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succes, error);
//     } else {
//         console.log('Your browser does not support geolocation');
//     }
// }
// const succes = (positon) => {
//     console.log(positon.coords.latitude)
//     console.log(positon.coords.longitude)
// }
// const error = (err) => {
//     console.log('The User have denied the request for Geolocation.');
// }
// getUserLocation();

const getUserLocation = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            resolve(navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition);
        } else {
             reject('The User have denied the request for Geolocation.');
        }
    })
}
getUserLocation()
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.coords.longitude);
        console.log(response.coords.latitude);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Comment: What's the problem? Your non-commented code is a promise already, right?

Comment: Looks like you want `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject)`. Right now, you're resolving with a reference to a function, not the result of a function.

Comment: the error in my browser say's 'TypeError: can't access property "longitude", response.coords is undefined'

Comment: Side note: Looks like you're falling into the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66747114/15299500), which isn't wrong, but it makes your code harder to read and manage.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close, the promise variant should look like this:

```js
const getUserLocation = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
        } else {
            reject('The User have denied the request for Geolocation.');
        }
    })
}
```

In the code above you pass the `resolve` and `reject` functions to `getCurrentPosition()` which calls them with either the geolocation position, or an error (in the case of `reject`) as sole argument.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just pass `resolve` and `reject` from the `Promise` function to the `getCurrentPosition` function.

```js
const getUserLocation = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject)
    } else {
      reject('The User have denied the request for Geolocation.');
    }
  })
}
getUserLocation()
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('success:', response.coords.longitude, response.coords.latitude);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('error:', err);
  })
```

Comment: Note that Stack Snippets are run in a sandboxed iframe without geolocation ability, so this always takes the error path.

Answer (score -1):

No. That's not the way to do it. There is nothing special about promises. It is not a new syntax added to the language. It is just an ordinary constructor/class that you can write yourself in pure javascript. Therefore there is nothing special that `resolve()` can do to convert callbacks to promises.

The correct way is to pass the `value` passed to the callback to the `resolve()` function:

```
// To avoid confusion I rename the resolve() and reject() function to
// AAA and BBB. This is to illustrate that they are just variables
// **you** declare and do not have any special syntax. This is also
// to avoid confusion with the Promise.resolve() static method.

const getUserLocation = () => {
    return new Promise((AAA, BBB) => {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(succes, error);
        } else {
            console.log('Your browser does not support geolocation');
            BBB(new Error('Your browser does not support geolocation')); // optional
        }

        const succes = (positon) => {
            console.log(positon.coords.latitude)
            console.log(positon.coords.longitude)
            AAA(position); // This is how you correctly resolve()
        }
        const error = (err) => {
            console.log('The User have denied the request for Geolocation.');
            BBB(err); // This is how you correctly reject()
        }
    });
}
```

Basically you need to copy your success() and error() functions into the scope of your `getUserLocation()` function and then you **MUST** resolve or reject **inside** those functions.